# Best way to enforce table participation

Tags: mysql, sql-server, database, oracle, database-design

I am not sure what will be the best way to enforce participation in the following database design (can be for SQL server, Oracle, mySQL etc.). I have two tables: Factory and Worker. I have created two rules for the design: 
1) Each factory hires at least one (or many) workers.
2) Each worker works for exactly one and only one factory.

I have created an ERD for the design:

[Factory]-||--- hire ---|<-[Worker]

The FACTORY table looks like this:

### Factory_ID (PK)    Factory_Name

1                  A
2                  B
3                  C

The WORKER table looks like this:

### Worker_ID (PK)    Worker_Name    Factory_ID (FK)

1                  Tom           2
2                  Ann           1
3                  Jan           1

In the worker table, the Factory_ID is the foreign key (FK) and it is set to NOT NULL because (the ERD said) each worker have to work for one factory and only one. This participation can be enforced by setting the FK (the Factory_ID field in the Worker table) to not null.

Here is my question, what is the best way to enforce the participation of - Each factory hires at least one workers? I.e. I need to make sure each factory_id have to be referenced in the worker table at least once. So now factory #3 does not hire anyone which violates the participation rule in the ERD.

I am wondering what will be the best way to enforce this participation?

Comment: Perhaps enforce at the application layer. Otherwise, how do you insert a new factory? It must have at least one employee at all times, but you can't assign an employee until the factory exists.

Comment: Thanks for the reply! Good point. I was thinking to have the application enforce that. I was curious if that can be done with the database layer? For instance use deferred FK?

Comment: If all application access is done through stored procedures then you can enforce the business rules there.  One sproc would handle adding a factory and its token employee within a single transaction.  The one to delete an employee would `RaIsError` if it is the last employee assigned to the factory.  And so on.  It is often useful to have a sproc that scans for _exceptions_, e.g. an office with no employees, that shouldn't happen but could.  They are conditions that aren't fatal to the application, but they ought to be chased down and cleaned up.

Comment: @AnnaJohnson, FK constraints won't help you to setup a 1+ cardinality. What you need is the NOT NULL field by itself. Said another way, the concept of FK is different than the one of NOT NULL, don't associate them. Then you understand why deferring FK wouldn't change anything.

Answer (score 5):

1+ constraints on relationships are usually implemented at the application layer.

- Stored Procedure
- Triggers
- Business layer of the backend
- Front end
- Any combination of the previous

The problem is that there's a timing concept to anticipate: with this kind of restrictions you would need a worker for your factory but your worker needs a factory himself: this is just simply impossible to implement this rule a synchronous maner.

A solution could be to manage a sort of backoffice to add the elements separately (for administrative purpose) and then implement within the public front the appropriate restrictions to match the 1+ requirements you have.
For example:

1. When removing a worker to a company, check that there's at least one left
2. Implementing a company replacement for when an employee changes his company, to ensure there's always one and only one company per employee.